# How can I shoot an arrow and have it always hit an enemy?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a bow which will shoot arrows that will always hit the enemy.

I'm not able to change the direction of the arrow, because I don't know the command for changing the side where arrow is going.

```
execute @e[type=arrow] ~ ~ ~ /???
```

Comment: Can you show us some more of what you actually tried and specify your question a bit further? Arqade tends to work a lot better when you show what you've already tried!

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: I just dont know the command of changing where arrow is going.

Comment: How should the game even know what you wanted to shoot?

Comment: I think closest to arrow will get shot. I will execute arrow and closest to it entity and change the direction straight i to that entity.

Comment: Then that will be the shooter, every time.

Comment: No, I can do like @e[!tag=HoldingBow] or something like this to not execute shooter.

Comment: And now everybody holds a bow, and your command does nothing.  Either way, though, *show us what you've tried*.  Give us something to work with, so we know what and how you're trying to solve this.  As it stands, your question is asking us to do everything for you, research and all.  Your effort goes a very long way to ensuring you get a good answer.

Comment: @Frank It's still a question. A poor (and lazy), but nethertheless valid question. Question validity doesn't take into account whether or not we should help the OP.

Answer (score 2):

I had a little thought about your question. It is not possible to change the direction of an arrow towards somebody, because you need vector calculations for that, which aren't possible in minecraft commands.
I think I have found an interesting alternative for you. The idea is that when an arrow hits the ground, close to the player, then it summons an invisible baby zombie with an arrow as rider. This baby zombie tries to move to the closest player. Once the baby zombie has arrived to its target, it gets killed and an arrow is summoned just above the player's head, making it seem as if the player got hit.
It works as following:

```
# give all the arrows in the ground a tag. [repeat] [unconditional] [always active]
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=arrow] add hit {inGround:1b}
# summon an invisible baby zombie at the location of the arrow with an arrow as passenger [chain] [unconditional] [always active]
/execute @e[tag=hit] ~ ~ ~ summon zombie ~ ~ ~ {IsBaby:1,Tags:["arrowZombie"],ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:0,Duration:20000000,ShowParticles:0b}],Passengers:[{id:arrow}]}
# delete the original arrow [chain] [unconditional] [always active]
/kill @e[tag=hit]
```

Now start a new chain of command blocks:

```
# check if the baby zombie is close to a player and summon an arrow above this player's head [repeat] [unconditional] [always active]
/execute @e[tag=arrowZombie] ~ ~ ~ execute @p[r=1] ~ ~ ~ summon Arrow ~ ~2.1 ~
# kill all baby zombies that are close to a player [chain] [unconditional] [always active]
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ kill @e[tag=arrowZombie,r=1]
```

following is an image of how an invisible baby zombie with an arrow as rider looks like:

[image]

This method has a few drawbacks though:

- The baby zombie has to see the player in order to track it, so the zombie doesn't always navigate towards the target.
- Every arrow that hits the ground summons a baby zombie. This is easily fixable, but I leave that up to you to figure out.
- If the arrow lands above a cliff, the baby zombie will fall down and die.
- Arrow effects and bow enchantments don't work with this method, because you summon a new arrow.

It's up to you to decide if this method suits your needs. Even if this doesn't work quite the way you want it, I'm sure you'll have a lot of fun testing it.

You can also leave the baby zombie part out and just summon an arrow above the head of the player closest to the original arrow, but once again: I'll leave that up to you to figure out.

Comment: I can actually make it even fancier, but that requires more research from my side.

Comment: that is actually good idea, but I want to hit not only players I want to hit all mobs in minecraft.